# mod_wsgi - Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, apache, redhat, wsgi

Using Red Hat, apache 2.4.6, worker mpm, mod_wsgi 4.6.5, and Python 3.7 When I start httpd I get the above error and:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

In the httpd error_log.

I'm using a python virtual environment created from a python installed from source under my home directory. I installed mod_wsgi from source using `--with-python=` option pointing to the python binary in my virtual environment, then I copied the mod_wsgi.so file into my apache modules directory as mod_wsgi37.so

I ran ldd on this file, and have a .conf file loading it into httpd like this:

`LoadFile /home/myUser/pythonbuild/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
 LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi37.so`

Then within my VirtualHost I have:

`WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi group=www threads=12 processes=2 python-path=/var/
    www/wsgi-scripts python-home=/var/www/wsgi-scripts/wsgi_env3
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/wsgi-scripts/test.py`

from my virtual environment:

sys.prefix:`'/var/www/wsgi-scripts/wsgi_env3'`

sys.real_prefix:`'/home/myUser/pythonbuild'`

When I switch to the system-installed mod_wsgi/python combo (remove python-home line from WSGIDaemonProcess, and change the .conf file to load the original mod_wsgi.so) it works fine. It seems like some path variables aren't getting set properly. Is there another way to set variables like PYTHONHOME that I'm missing? How can I fix my install?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so, could you provide the answer?

Comment: I never found a solution to this.
I think I switched back to using the system Python for the time being.
Open to any tips/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and I found that my manually specified `LoadModule wsgi_module "/path_to_conda/"` was being ignored because the previously apache-wide wsgi mod was being loaded. You can check if `wsgi.*` is present in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.

If that is the case, consider `a2dismod wsgi` to disable the apache wsgi that loads the wrong python.

Answer (score 0):

As I ran into this problem recently, I found a solution that works in my environment.
I don't work with a virtual environment, but have a non-standard python installation in my home folder (compiled and installed without root access) - this should be similar to a virtual environment.

My virtual host config is structured as follows:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/myuser/usr/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi home=/path/to/my/project/folder processes=10 threads=10
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/folder/wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

First, I omitted python-path completely. Further, WSGIPythonHome should point to the parent folder of the `bin/`, `lib/` and `include/` directories with the python libraries.
I made the mistake to point it towards the `bin/` folder.
Consequentially, WSGI could not load the default libraries, even when I added them to the python path manually via `WSGIPythonPath`.