# keep getting the Fatal Python error with mod_wsgi and apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

```
Current thread 0x00007f5aa48af880 (most recent call first):
no Python frame
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = /var/www/project/venu/bin/python
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = /var/www/project/venu/bin/python
  sys.base_prefix = '/opt/python3.8.2'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/opt/python3.8.2'
  sys.executable = '/var/www/project/venu/bin/python
  sys.prefix = '/opt/python3.8.2'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/opt/python3.8.2'
  sys.path = [
    '/opt/python3.8.2/lib/python38.zip',
    '/opt/python3.8.2/lib/python3.8',
    '/opt/python3.8.2/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named encodings

Current thread (most recent call first)
```

I have complied python 3.8.2 with django 2.2. it run locally fine but when i try to deploy it with Apache and mod_wsgi 4.7.1 and getting the above error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't find the URL now, but a few weeks ago, one of the Django developers concluded it was due to a bug in mod_wsgi and that he is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my specific `LoadModule wsgi_module "/path_to_conda"` was being ignored because of the previously enabled wsgi apache mod. I had to disable it first with `a2dismod wsgi`, [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673425/1218179).